# how to make htaccess rewrite rule for multiple sub directories

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel

I have 3 subdirectories with `index.php` files with same url params:

- `example https://example.com/one/index.php?c=onestar`
- `https://example.com/two/index.php?c=onestar`
- `https://example.com/three/index.php?c=onestar`

I am using the below code for removing `.php` from URL

```
RewriteEngine On

options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

how to make it SEO friendly `https://example.com/one/index/onestar`. Also how to make it dynamic for adding multiple directories in the future like `https://example.com/four/index/onestar`

Comment: @anubhava do you know solution for this ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about htaccess, I was trying some rewrite rule code

Comment: RewriteRule ^index/([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?c=$1

Comment: Anything you can do to help

Comment: RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]]

options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

Comment: Please edit your question and provide this code there.

Comment: I am using this for removing .php from url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this code in site root .htaccess:

```sh
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# http => https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# /one/index/onestar => /one/index.php?c=onestar
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/index/([\w-]+)/?$ $1/index.php?c=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

# hide .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks it's working. But is it right if I make it dynamic instead of using (one|two|three), I use (.*)

Comment: Yes I can be made dynamic, rule updated further.